# Getting a Numeric[T] for generic T (if available) in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I need to get a `Numeric[T]` if available (so I guess an `Option[Numeric[T]]`) for the following situation:

```scala
class Foo[T]() {
  def t:T
  def doSomeProcessing():Unit = ... // This is where I need an Option[Numeric[T]]
}

class Bar {
  def foos: Seq[Foo[_]]
  def doSomethingWithFoos():Unit = {
    for (foo <- foos) {
      foo.doSomeProcessing()
    }
  }
}
```

I can add `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` as necessary / helpful, but I'd like to avoid an explicit listing of each and every possible Numeric, which is what I have right now:

```scala
val numOpt: Option[Numeric[T]] = classTag[T] match {
  case longTag if longTag == classTag[Long] => Some(Numeric.LongIsIntegral.asInstanceOf[Numeric[T]])
  case intTag if intTag == classTag[Int] => Some(Numeric.IntIsIntegral.asInstanceOf[Numeric[T]])
      ...
  case _ => None
}
```

Is there a more elegant / comprehensive solution? Thanks!

Edit: I tried doing:

```scala
class Foo[T](implicit num: Numeric[T] = null) {
  def t:T
  val numOpt:Option[Numeric[T]] = Option(num)
}
```

But that didn't work (numOpt = None for T = Long), probably because Foo is actually part of a long class hierarchy with multiple this / super calls...

Update: the issue is that Foo actually has four constructors, and all need to take an (implicit num: Numeric[T] = null), but only one of them is allowed to have a default parameter. I guess I would have to find a way to get rid of three of them, or manually feed in `null` as needed.

Comment: What would you do if there is no Numeric for `T`. Also, you do not even known what T is because you have a sequence of `Foo[_]` you already loose the type. Finally it seems you want to get the value in runtime whereas a typeclass is resolved at compile time. Overall, this seems like a bad designed solution, what is your meta problem, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Ah, I realized I didn't transcribe the actual situation correctly, inside the Bar for loop I actually call a separate method in Foo, and it's inside *that* function I need `Option[Numeric[T]]`.

Comment: @Jxtps If you need that Option somewhere, you need to either keep passing it around to every method or have your implicit def that provides the Option[Numeric[T]] in scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an implicit `Numeric` parameter with a default value:

```
class Foo[T] private(val t: T)(val numeric: Option[Numeric[T]])
object Foo {
  def apply[T](t: T)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T] = null) = new Foo(t)(Option(numeric))
}
```

You can use it as such

```
class Bar {
  //Note that I've explicitly put in Foo[Int] here because it doesn't understand it otherwise (not sure why).
  def foos: Seq[Foo[_]] = Seq(Foo("blah"), Foo[Int](39))
  def doSomethingWithFoos():Unit = {
    for (foo <- foos) {
      println(foo.t)
      foo.numeric match {
        case Some(num: Numeric[foo.t.type]) => println(num.plus(foo.t, foo.t))
        case None => println("Not numeric")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
blah
Not numeric
39
78
```

```html
<script src="https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CDSbri6WQwSYtIoR4Swl8A.js"></script>
```

If you don't want the boilerplate of an apply method, you can also define your own method to supply `Option` instances and directly use an implicit in your constructor.

```
class Foo[T](val t: T)(implicit val numeric: Option[Numeric[T]])

implicit def implicitOption[T](implicit t: T = null): Option[T] = Option(t)
```

Link to Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pUOw5tFNRtGZVbHNHx7QYw

Otherwise, you can use a nullable type instead of an `Option`.

```
class Foo[T](val t: T)(implicit val numeric: Numeric[T] = null)
```

Link to Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/AOGNZSirT0C7Cy0Po6vZXw

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial edit & subsequent update, that works for the example code I provided (so I will mark your answer as correct), but it unfortunately doesn't work quite as conveniently in my actual case due to the extra constructors and the class being used in an actual class hierarchy (can't `extend Foo.apply(...)`).

Comment: @Jxtps You can always put the implicit parameter in your primary constructor, but then you'll either have to use a nullable Numeric (give up Option) or make an implicit def that provides an `Option[Numeric[T]]` given a `Numeric[T]`